# 1093 - You can't specify target table 'is_items' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I'm trying to set the values of the column 'id' by order, but my query isn't working:

```
UPDATE is_items SET id=(SELECT max(id)+1 FROM is_items WHERE id<160)
```

Error:

```
[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'is_items' for update in FROM clause
```

I saw other asks about the same problem, but I can't understand very well the solution...

Thanks in advance,

King Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two steps by using a user defined variable:

```
set @id := (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM is_items WHERE id<160);
UPDATE is_items SET id=@id;
```

Comment: @vince yes - that is what OP's query does. I just addressed the syntax problem (not any potential logic problems)